# Best way to increment d3 attribute

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a piece of code where I want to increment/decrement the attribute values of d3 objects.

I did it using the following:

```
var diff=5;
d3Selector.attr("x",function(){
    return Number(d3Selector.attr("x"))+diff;
});
```

In JS simply `+=` works. Is there a better way to do this than getting the current value and adding and setting it again?

The following was created with the suggestion of **Robert Longson** and the I'm using d3_v4. The problem here is that they are concatenated(as strings) rather than number addition, which I tried to solve using `Number()` but it gives an error saying `Must be lvalue`.

```js
function mov() {
  var diffX = 5;
  d3.select("#ee")["_groups"][0][0]["attributes"].x.value += diffX;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.3.0/d3.js"></script>
<button onclick="mov()">Click to move</button>
<br>
<svg width="400" height="400">
  <rect id="ee" x="10" y="10" width="100" height="100" />
</svg>
```

Comment: does d3Selector[0][0].x.baseVal.value += diff; work for you. If not create a fiddle or a stack snippet that's runnable so I can show you what to do and test my answer.

Comment: No but this works: `d3child["_groups"][0][0]["attributes"].cx.value += diff`

Comment: @RobertLongson Is the difference caused by the version change? I tried with d3_v4 and updated the question by adding code snippet

Answer (score 4):

Use the SVG DOM.

```js
function mov() {
  var diffX = 5;
  d3.select("#ee").node().x.baseVal.value += diffX;

  // or alternatively
  // document.getElementById("ee").x.baseVal.value += diffX;
  // as suggested by altocumulus
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.3.0/d3.js"></script>
<button onclick="mov()">Click to move</button>
<br>
<svg width="400" height="400">
  <rect id="ee" x="10" y="10" width="100" height="100" />
</svg>
```

Comment: This approach relies on accessing D3's internals which is strongly discouraged. Doing it without D3 will be faster and easier to read: `document.getElementById("ee").x.baseVal.value += diffX;`.

Comment: @altocumulus I've updated the answer not to use internals but to use the standard d3 node method instead.

Comment: Since OP explicitly asked for a D3 way, this might in fact be the most accurate answer.

Comment: could one add a transition on top of this ?

Answer (score 0):

**D3 setters and getters**

I believe that the understanding of how setters and getters work in D3 can shed some light here.

You asked for a better way to increment a given attribute, instead of *"getting the current value and adding and setting it again"*, and you said:

> In JS simply += works

So, why can't we do the same using D3? Let's see.

Given this very basic code:

```
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg");

var circle = svg.append("circle").attr("cx", 50)
    .attr("cy", 50).attr("r", 5);
```

It paints a circle at (50,50). We can get the `cx` value of that circle using a getter. A getter is basically the same function, but with only 1 argument:

```
var x = circle.attr("cx");//returns 50
```

So, what happens if we just add a value to x, using the JS `+=`?

```
var x += 100;//returns 50100
```

50 + 100 is not 50100. We just discovered that the value of `x` is a string, not a number. To convert it to a number let's do this:

```
var x = circle.attr("cx");
x = +x;
x += 100;
```

Now, `x` is 150. We successfully added a value to `x`.

And here comes the most important part: this is not going to change the position of the circle. `x` is just a variable that gets the value of that circle's `cx` using a **getter**.

Changing `x` value is just that, changing the variable's value. It will not affect the element.

To change the position of the circle (without manipulating `baseVal`), we have to use a **setter**, that is the function with 2 arguments:

```
circle.attr("cx", x);//now the circle moves to (150,50)
```

**Conclusion**: that pattern (getting the current value, adding something, setting the value again) may seem cumbersome and not very elegant, but that's the standard pattern in D3.